# How to receive Intent in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, android-bundle

Honestly I did somesearch about this before asking. how to receive intent from activity to `fragmentactivity` I am trying to use viewpager. I am having error here in get arguments`Bundle extras = getArguments();`

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ImageView   imageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

   ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
       // Listitem item = new Listitem("1", "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/android_logo.png");//I used to add it staticly

        Bundle extras = getArguments();
        if (extras != null) {
            extras = extras.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST);
            personArrayList.add(item);        }
    //    DemoObjectFragment f = DemoObjectFragment.newInstance(personArrayList);

        ViewPager    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Log.d("s", "singleview");


        DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter =      new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager(),personArrayList);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras()`

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks man, but I got error here ,  `extras = extras.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST);`what it should be ?

Comment: "extras.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST);" is returning you ParcelableList that you want to put to a Bundle object. I can tell you that even without the stacktrace :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need two Activities. Since you didn't post the `Activity` that starts the posted `Activity`, I have made a simple one that contains only a `Button` that starts the shown `Activity`.

Take note of the commented steps. There are six steps total.

The first `Activity` gets the `ArrayList` data, the passes it to the second `Activity`, which in turn gives in to the `DemoCollectionAdapter`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Step 1: Build an ArrayList to pass to the next Activity
                ArrayList<Listitem> items = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
                items.add(new Listitem("1", "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/android_logo.png"));
                items.add(new Listitem("2", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/B28Ca.jpg?s=328&g=1"));

                // Step 2: Create an Intent to start the next Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);

                // Step 3: Put the ArrayList into the Intent
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(SingleViewActivity.ARG_PERSON_LIST, items);

                // Step 4: Start the next Activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public static final String ARG_PERSON_LIST = "ARG_PERSON_LIST";

    private ArrayList<Listitem> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

        // Step 5: Get the Bundle from the Intent that started this Activity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            // Step 6: Get the data out of the Bundle
            items = extras.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST);
        } else {
            items = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        }

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        DemoCollectionPagerAdapter adapter = new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), items);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked . your amazing man . by the way i dont know if it needs a new question, but I cannot swipe the image..the xml is correct , it contains viewpager

Comment: Your `getCount` method in `DemoCollectionPagerAdapter` should return the size of the list instead of 1. For example. `public int getCount() { return this. personArrayList.size(); }`

Comment: nop it didnt work public int getCount() {

                return this.personArrayList.size();            } can you help me with it?

Comment: Then add more than one `Listitem` to the list

Comment: I didnt understand , how to add more `listitem` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't swipe. Look under Step 1 in my answer here. I have done `items.add(new Listitem(...` twice.

Comment: Yes i saw that but in my case i am clicking on gridview , i guess i need the position of the image iin gridview so ica swipe it .. right ? If you need any code tell me

Comment: I suggest you make a new question with the code for the data that comes from the GridView. If you can't swipe on the ViewPager, that means the list that you are receiving only contains one `Listitem`. It is as simple as that

Comment: Okay man ill post new question tomorow, ill do some search before. Ill update you thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an ParcelableList object to a Bundle variable.

```
extras = extras.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST); //change it
```

Assign it to a `ParcelableList` rather than to `extras`.

EDIT :

Try this,

```
ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList;
// Listitem item = new Listitem("1", "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/android_logo.png");//I used to add it staticly

Bundle extras = getArguments();
if (extras != null) {
    personArrayList = (ArrayList<Listitem>) extras.getParcelableArrayList("jh");
    personArrayList.add(item); 
    ....       
}
```

Comment: I am sorry i am new to android.. to what should I change it ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. See the edited answer

Comment: it didnt work , error in getarguments() and below arraylist , I want to receive an intent from an activity to thie fragment, where is item ?

Comment: @Moudiz - your error in that `item` is not defined, so it can't be added to the list

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your fragment object, you also have set the argument in the created fragment object.

Something like this...

```
Fragment f = new Fragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("someNum", 0);
f.setArguments(args);
```

And then in onCreate() or onCreateView method of fragment, get the argument.

```
getArguments().getInt("someNum");
```

In your case, it would be parcelable or serializable object.

Comment: The question is about Activity, not Fragment